# Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Software Center uses?

Tags: apt, software-center, bandwidth, resource-limiting

Whenever I am downloading packages using Ubuntu Software Center (or any package manager for that matter), my Internet connection slows to an absolute crawl. In fact, most requests timeout.

Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Software Center uses when downloading packages?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the software centre uses `apt-get` (and I'm not actually sure that it does, so you will need to try this yourself), you should be able to do the following:

Create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/76download` with the following content:

```
Acquire
{
    Queue-mode "access";
    http
    {
        Dl-Limit "150";
    };
};
```

That limits `apt-get` to **150KB/s**. I haven't tried it myself, so I can't verify that it will work for you.

Comment: I'm just as happy if 'apt-get' can be bandwidth-limited..

Comment: Can I ask if this did work for the Software Centre?

Comment: @flute: I'm afraid I only tried it for apt :)

Comment: software centre uses apt internally....