# How can I increase the bandwidth sharing between processes?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to limit the bandwidth that Software Center uses?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5192/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-bandwidth-that-software-center-uses)

How can I increase the bandwidth sharing between **processes**? I mean, sometimes i am updating ubuntu and the software updater gets all the bandwidth while other programs like browser/ping won't even have enough to barely do a dns lookup...

Using ubuntu 10.10 LTS